# unit test for MvcHtmlString type

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, unit-testing

I have a method that returns MvcHtmlString, so in my unit test I'm trying to make sure that the right type comes back:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetTeamNameByAlignmentTest()
{    
    var target01 = MockEventData().First().GetTeamNameByAlignment("HoMe");    
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(target01, typeof(MvcHtmlString));
}
```

However the test fails

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType failed.  Expected type:<System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString>. Actual type:<System.Web.Mvc.{Dynamic}.DynamicMvcHtmlString>
```

How do I properly test for MvcHtmlString return type?

EDIT:
The Method:

```
 public MvcHtmlString GetTeamNameByAlignment(String alignment)
        {
        StringBuilder teamName = new StringBuilder();
        if (Participants.First().Alignment.ToLower() == alignment.ToLower())
        {
            teamName.Append(Participants.First().Team.TeamName);
            if (Participants.First().Winning == true)
            {
                teamName.Insert(0, "<b>");
                teamName.Append("</b>");
            } 
        }

        if (Participants.Last().Alignment.ToLower() == alignment.ToLower())
        {

            teamName.Append(Participants.Last().Team.TeamName);
            if (Participants.Last().Winning == true)
            {
                teamName.Insert(0, "<b>");
                teamName.Append("</b>");
            } 
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(teamName.ToString());
    }
```

EDIT 2:

Mocked data:

```
private static IQueryable<Event> MockEventData()
    {
        Team team01 = new Team();
        team01.TeamName = "HomeTeam";

        Team team02 = new Team();
        team02.TeamName = "AwayTeam";


        EventParticipant participant01 = new EventParticipant();
        participant01.Alignment = "home";
        participant01.Team = team01;
        participant01.Winning = false;
        participant01.totalScore = 77;

        EventParticipant participant02 = new EventParticipant();
        participant02.Alignment = "away";
        participant02.Team = team02;
        participant02.Winning = true;
        participant02.totalScore = 99;


        Event event01 = new Event();
        event01.Participants = new List<EventParticipant> {participant01, participant02};

        IQueryable<Event> events = new List<Event> { event01 }.AsQueryable();

        return events;
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us the method that you are trying to test?

Comment: What is the `MockEventData` class that you are using in your unit test? What does it return? How is it implemented?

Comment: `MockEventData` returns an `IQueryable<Event>` which contains mocked data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this source code](http://wikiencyclopedia.net/ASP.NET_MVC/ASP.NET_MVC/2.0.0.0/DEVDIV/depot/devdiv/feature/Mvc/main/src/SystemWebMvc/Mvc/MvcHtmlString.cs/4/MvcHtmlString.cs) for `MvcHtmlString`, `DynamicMvcHtmlString` looks to be a runtime-created subclass of `MvcHtmlString`. With that in mind, how about changing your assertion to:

```
Assert.IsTrue(target01 is MvcHtmlString);
```

?